# Pi 3 running windows core freezing

Tags: windows-iot, logfiles

I have a system working 24/7 which behaves itself most of the time (days) running a simple browser app (Kiosk to single web app) in IOTstartup over WiFi. Is there a way I can get at any error reporting that may give me a clue to its sudden bouts of crashing?

Comment: Windows Device Portal might offer a solution, but I am having a bit of a faff setting it up as it doesn't seem to want to download as part of Windows 10

Comment: Looks as though it is to do with the WiFi timing out over night

Comment: No pattern seems to be emerging, just seems to stop connecting. Have increase the time out, added no sleep functions and messed with the core visibility and it still white screens. Will keep searching...

Comment: Have added WebViewNavigationCompleteEventArgs to see if anything reported

Comment: It is looking more and more as though this was to do with the environment the application was being used it (WiFi connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking very much like an infrastructure issue on the hardware location weak WiFi signal enough for day to day use, but not 24/7.

Comment: New WiFi node added